# I'm trying to know the country that pays the highest salary from

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select last_name, country_name, SUM(salary)
from employees e JOIN departments d ON (e.department_id= d.department_id) 
JOIN locations L ON (d.location_id = L.location_id) 
JOIN Countries Cc ON (L.country_id = Cc.country_id) 
JOIN regions Rr ON (Cc.region_id = Rr.region_id) 
GROUP BY country_name;
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you posted wouldn't compile; it lacks `LAST_NAME` in the `GROUP BY` (which is, basically, wrong as it would make what you're doing *impossible*) or - a better idea - remove it from the `SELECT` statement's column list.

Using `RANK` analytic function, you'd then have

```
WITH data
     AS (  SELECT country_name,
                  SUM (salary) sumsal,
                  RANK () OVER (ORDER BY SUM (salary) DESC) rn
             FROM employees e
                  JOIN departments d ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
                  JOIN locations L ON (d.location_id = L.location_id)
                  JOIN Countries Cc ON (L.country_id = Cc.country_id)
                  JOIN regions Rr ON (Cc.region_id = Rr.region_id)
         GROUP BY country_name)
SELECT country_name, sumsal
  FROM data
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

---

I don't have your tables nor data so - for illustration - I'll use Scott's sample schema. Simplified, it would be like this:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  order by 2 desc;

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        10      13750        --> this is a department you need
        20      10995
        30       9400
```

So:

```
SQL> WITH data
  2       AS (  SELECT deptno,
  3                    SUM (sal) sumsal,
  4                    RANK () OVER (ORDER BY SUM (sal) DESC) rn
  5               FROM emp
  6           GROUP BY deptno)
  7  SELECT deptno, sumsal
  8    FROM data
  9   WHERE rn = 1;

    DEPTNO     SUMSAL
---------- ----------
        10      13750

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to only show the best rows of your intermediate result. As of Oracle 12c you could use the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS` clause for this. Until Oracle 11g, you should use a window function instead:

```
SELECT country_name, sum_salary
FROM
(
  select 
    c.country_name,
    SUM(e.salary) AS sum_salary,
    MAX(SUM(e.salary)) OVER () AS max_sum_salary
  from employees e 
  JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
  JOIN locations l ON d.location_id = l.location_id
  JOIN countries c ON l.country_id = c.country_id
  GROUP BY c.country_name
)
WHERE sum_salary = max_sum_salary
ORDER BY country_name;
```